# Improving Grouping Speed in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a web form where I need to group items/rows based on some criteria. It has multilevel grouping and that is why rendering items in the gird becomes very tedious process for the server.

Here is what I do currently. (This is for only 3 level).

```
protected void ResultGrid_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gdR in ResultGrid.Rows)
    {
        Label lblClass = (Label)gdR.FindControl("lblClass");
        Label lblCategory = (Label)gdR.FindControl("lblCategory");
        Label lblCompartment = (Label)gdR.FindControl("lblCompartment");
        Panel pnlClassLinks = (Panel)gdR.FindControl("pnlClassLinks");

        foreach (GridViewRow gdRIn in ResultGrid.Rows)
        {
           if (gdRIn.RowIndex != gdR.RowIndex)
           {
             Label lblClassIn = (Label)gdRIn.FindControl("lblClass");
             Label lblCategoryIn = (Label)gdRIn.FindControl("lblCategory");
             Label lblCompartmentIn = (Label)gdRIn.FindControl("lblCompartment");

             if(lblClassIn.Text == lblClass.Text)
               {
                   if(lblCategoryIn.Text == lblCategory.Text)
                   {
                       if(lblCompartmentIn.Text == lblCompartment.Text)
                       {
                           LinkButton lnkBtn = new LinkButton();
                           // lnkBtn Properties added
                           pnlClassLinks.Controls.Add(lnkBtn);
                           if (pnlClassLinks.Controls.Count > 2)
                           {
                               pnlClassLinks.Width = 150;
                           }
                           if (gdR.Visible)
                           {
                               dr.Visible = false;
                           }
                       }
                   } 
               }
           }
        }
      LinkButton lnkGroupEdit = (LinkButton)gdR.FindControl("lnkGroupEdit");
      lnkGroupEdit.OnClientClick = "editGroup();";
    }
}
```

As it clearly shows, the rows iteration is too much, when the number of rows in gridview increases. So, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: For me, the solution is to group the data before the rendering...

Comment: @Aristos, if you mean `PreRender`, that's what I've done. There are other  processing being carried in `DataBound` method, and once that is done, the `PreRender` sees that it is grouped correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a GenericCollection. Include your customised properties like (width, cssClass, visibility...). Then bind this collection to the gridView as a dataSource.

```
gridView.DataSource=  List_CustomModel;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: I have to generate Linkbuttons at the same time for each row either grouped or not. I think this is not possible using a Generic Collection.

Comment: It is possible. Add the linkButton Code in your gridViewItem template.
And bind the Visible attribute to your custom_Model property.

Answer (score 0):

this is a scope from a code i manipulate

```
 ` 
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="LtBodac" runat="server" Text="BODACC" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
     <HeaderStyle CssClass="css-bodacc" />
     <ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox Visible='<%#Eval("Bodacc") %>' ID="TbDateBodac" CssClass="datebox source-manuel css-bodacc CustomDateMercure" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DateBodac")%>' /><asp:HiddenField Visible='<%#Eval("Bodacc") %>' ID="HfOldDateBodac" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("DateBodac")%>' /> </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

NB:#Eval("Bodacc") :Boddac is a property in my model.